# Laravel 5.4 auth session is not working

Tags: session, authentication, laravel-5.4

I'll try to explain this weird behavior as detailed as possible. The problem is, that the user is logged out after login. So, the login actually happens, session file is set in storage folder, but after another click it's logging me out. It is interesting that this is happening only on production/shared hosting, on localhost it is working fine. What I've tried so far:

1. Changed the file to database in session.php
2. Changed the session name - it works, but only for couple of hours!
3. Debugged Exceptions/handler.php unauthenticated method
4. Fiddled with Kernel.php and tried every possible way that came up in Google
5. Tried redefining and regrouping middleware groups

Here is my route file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    /**
     * Auth
     */
    Route::get('/login', 'Admin\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Admin\Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::get('/logout', 'Admin\Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\AdminController@index');

    /**
     * Structure
     */
    Route::prefix('structure')->group(function () {
        Route::resource('menu', 'Admin\Structure\MenuController');
        Route::resource('template-group', 'Admin\Structure\TemplateGroupController');
        Route::resource('property', 'Admin\Structure\PropertyController');
        Route::resource('property-type', 'Admin\Structure\PropertyTypeController');
        Route::resource('property-value', 'Admin\Structure\PropertyValueController');
        Route::resource('property-value-order', 'Admin\Structure\PropertyValueOrderController');
        Route::resource('template', 'Admin\Structure\TemplateController');
    });
    Route::resource('structure', 'Admin\StructureController');


    /**
     * Content
     */
    Route::prefix('content')->group(function () {
        Route::resource('page', 'Admin\Content\PageController');
    });
    Route::resource('content', 'Admin\ContentController');


});
});
```

Comment: try to open your page using incognito mode. I also had this issue but only on localhost. I didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: Tried that as well. Gives me a token mismatch exception

Comment: Did you fix that issue? Me too having the same issue.Please share the answer if you got it.

Comment: @Science the only workaround I've found, was changing the remember option set to true by default in Auth/LoginController. Auth::guard()->attempt($credentiasl, true)